# FEM assembly using MPI

Tags: c++, matrix, mpi

I am trying to solve the Poisson equation using finite element method with MPI.
I already have the connectivity matrix and also I have the x and y coordinate of each node. I've broadcasted the connectivity and coordinate matrix to all processors. let's say that we have N nodes, so the global stiffness matrix would be N*N. Imagine we have just two processors and we send just the half of elements to each processor. Now my question is should I define a local matrix of N/2*N/2 for each processors or should I define a N*N matrix for all and each processor will fulfill its part in the procedure. In this case how can I gather the ultimate matrix in the master process?
If I define the local matrix of N/2*N/2 for each processor, some elements maybe share the same element in both processors and this would be a problem for assembly. I am attaching my code and I would be grateful if you could help me.

Comment: all these raw poiters in modern C++ make my head spin...

Answer (score 0):

This question covers a whole range of issues and is very difficult to answer in general. However, the simplest way to get some sort of parallelisation into dense matrix/vector operations is probably to replicate the vectors across the processes but split the matrix by row. If the matrix A is N x N, each process therefore has a matrix A2 of N/2 x N and vectors of size N. To compute y = A b, you do a local multiplication of y = A2 x b on each process (perfectly parallel) then accumulate the partial results across processes using an MPI_Allreduce on y.

This should work OK for small process counts. For a scalable algorithm you would need also to decompose the vectors across processes, and exploit the structure of A (which is probably very sparse).